# Computation of Wigner Functions

Tags: integration, quantum-optics, complex-numbers, wigner-transform

The Wigner function can be computed as the Fourier transform of the Weyl-ordered characteristic function:
$$
W(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\pi^2} \int e^{\lambda^* \alpha - \lambda \alpha^*} C_W(\lambda) d^2\lambda
$$
as given by Eq. $(3.136)$ of "Introductory Quantum Optics" by C. Gerry and P. Knight, where the integral is over all space.  When trying to compute $W$ for a given state I often encounter integrals of the form:
$$
\int e^{a \lambda^* + b \lambda - c |\lambda|^2} d^2\lambda
$$
for $a, b, c \in \mathbb{C}$ with $Re(c) > 0$.  How does one compute such an integral?

Here is my attempt:
Let $\lambda = x + ip$ such that the corresponding Jacobian determinant is
$$
 J = \begin{vmatrix}
 \dfrac{\partial \lambda^*}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial \lambda^*}{\partial p}\\[1em]
 \dfrac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial \lambda}{\partial p} \end{vmatrix}
 = \begin{vmatrix}
  1 & -i \\
  1 & i \end{vmatrix}
 = 2i
$$
and hence
\begin{align}\label{WFcnCIntIdent}
 \int e^{a \lambda^* + b \lambda - c |\lambda|^2} d^2\lambda
 &= |2 i| \int \int  e^{a (x - ip) + b (x + ip)- c (x^2 + p^2)} dx dp \nonumber \\
 &= 2 \int e^{-c x^2 + (a+b) x} dx \int e^{-c p^2 + (b-a) i p} dp \nonumber \\
 &= 2 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{c}} \exp \Bigg[ \frac{(a+b)^2}{4 c} \Bigg] \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{c}} \exp \Bigg[ \frac{-(b-a)^2}{4 c} \Bigg] \nonumber \\
 &= \frac{2 \pi}{c} \exp \Bigg[ \frac{(a+b)^2}{4 c} - \frac{(b-a)^2}{4 c} \Bigg] \nonumber \\
 &= \frac{2 \pi}{c} e^{ab/c}
\end{align}
as the integrals are Gaussian.

Is this the correct approach?  When using the result I obtained my calculations are consistently off by factors of two so I think the correct result might be:
$$
\int e^{a \lambda^* + b \lambda - c |\lambda|^2} d^2\lambda \overset{?}{=} \frac{\pi}{c} e^{ab/c},
$$
but I do not see where I went wrong.  I might be misunderstanding the complex Jacobian or some other details.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is the definition of integration measure $d^2 \lambda=d \lambda^*d\lambda$ you adopted alright?

Comment: @Sunyam Looking back in the book I found that $d^2\lambda = d [Re(\lambda)] d [Im(\lambda)]$ so it seems that I was using the wrong integration measure which accounts for the factor of two discrepancy.  Thanks!

Comment: [Some conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiprobability_distribution#Characteristic_functions).